# Esql how to use select statement to retrieve value from input xml

Tags: xml, select, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have an input xml that looks something like this

```
<log>
    <line>
        <id>1</id>
    <line>
        <id>2</id>
    <otherLine>
        <id>2</id>
        <field>
            12345-67
        </field>
    </otherLine>
</log>
```

What I do in esql is basically iterate over every `<line>` element and I want retrieve the value from `<otherLine>` where the `<id>` values match.

I have code like this:

```
declare inDoc reference to InputRoot.XMLNSC.log;
declare line reference to inDoc;
declare fieldValue character;

move line firstchild name 'line';
while lastmove(line) do

    set fieldValue = select r.field from inDoc.otherLine[] as r where r.id = line.id;
    -- I want this to be null when hitting the line with <id>1</id> and 12345-67 and hitting the line with <id>2</id>

    move line nextsibling name 'line';
end while
```

I get the following error when I try to deploy the code:

```
BIP2497E: (MyApp_flow.Main, <line number of select statement>) : Illegal data type for target. A list field reference is required. 

The expression supplying the target must evaluate to a value of a suitable type. The given expression cannot possibly do so. 

Correct the syntax of your ESQL expression in node 'MyApp_flow.Main', around line and column '<line number of the select statement>', then redeploy the message flow.
```

I'm wondering what the right way to accomplish this in esql would be

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use `the`,`item`, and `fieldvalue` in the select statement like this

```
set fieldValue = the(select item fieldvalue(r.field) from inDoc.otherLine[] as r where r.id = line.id);
```